# How to add UISegmentedControl in MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to add SegmentedControl to my MKMapView With three Segments

1. StandardView
2. SatelliteView
3. HybridView

and we can change map type by taping segments

i have try some code

```
- (void)indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl *)aSegmentedControl {

NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];
segControl= [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];

if((segControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0)){
    _mapView = MKMapTypeStandard;
}
if((segControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1)){
    _mapView = MKMapTypeSatellite;
}
else {
    _mapView = MKMapTypeHybrid;
}
```

}

Comment: What are you doing in indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl?? adding another segment control

Comment: try this tutorial http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-segmented-controluisegmentedcontrol-tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey try with this condition `segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0` instead of this `segControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0`

here problem with single = sign

and Also try like this bellow code..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      segControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil]];
      [segControl addTarget:self action:@selector(indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
      [segControl setFrame:CGRectMake(50,20,200,44)];//set frame which you want
      [self.view addSubview:segControl];
}

- (void)indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl *)aSegmentedControl {
    switch (aSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0:
                map.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
                break;
            case 1:
                map.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
                break;
            case 2:
                map.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: (((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex)  where sender Undeclared

Comment: @Dinesh_ sorry dude now i update before you put comment dude use aSegmentedControl.selectedIndex..  try it dude see Updated code..

Answer (score 0):

Listen for `UIControlEventValueChanged`. So connect your segmentedControl to an `IBAction` like this:

```
-(IBAction)changeMapType:(id)sender{
   UISegmentedControl *seg=(UISegmentedControl*)sender;
   if(seg.selectedSegmentIndex==0){//not = but ==
      _mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeStandard;
   }
   if(seg.selectedSegmentIndex==1){
      _mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeSatellite;
   }
   if(seg.selectedSegmentIndex==2){
      _mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeHybrid;
   }
}
```

Comment: control does not check for changeMapType: method

Comment: I don't get you..it's really simple, you have to connect the action valueChanged in the xib with a method like that. If you're adding the segmentControl by code use the @Paras Joshi solution.